# how to add filters in QueryBuilders.matchQuery() to get some matching documents based on filter

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am able to fetch documents from elasticsearch which is matching to my input code `ABC-123` with the below java code. But now, i want to add one more condition / filter here,
I want to fetch all my matching code `ABC-123` who's `Type` is only `Reg`.

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX); 
searchRequest.types(TYPE);
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder2 = new SearchSourceBuilder();
QueryBuilder qb=QueryBuilders.matchQuery("code", code);
searchSourceBuilder.query(qb);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse1 = null;
try {
     searchResponse1 = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.getLocalizedMessage();
}
SearchHit[] searchHits1 = searchResponse1.getHits().getHits();
Replacement linkId = null;
Replacement replacement = null;
List<Replacement> linkIDList=new ArrayList<Replacement>();
for (SearchHit hit1 : searchHits1) {
    linkId = new Replacement();
     Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap1 = hit1.getSourceAsMap();
     linkId.setLink_id(sourceAsMap1.get("code"));
     linkIDList.add(linkId);
}
```

Please find my data below.

```
id      link_id         code            Type
1001    2001            ABC-123         Reg
1002    2002            ABC-345         Reg
1003    2003            ABC-123         Act
1004    2004            ABC-123         Reg
```

If am trying to search for `ABC-123`, am expecting only

```
id      link_id         code            Type
1001    2001            ABC-123         Reg
1004    2004            ABC-123         Reg
```

It, should not consider the below record. because its type is `Act`.

```
id      link_id         code            Type
1003    2003            ABC-123         Act
```

Can anyone have any idea, that how can i add `filter` in my java code. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your constraints inside a `bool/must/filter` query, like this:

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("code", code))
    .filter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("Type", "Reg"));
searchSourceBuilder.query(qb);
```